# Erro ao abrir o arquivo excel

Tags: php

Bom dia

Estou gerando um relatório em php e mysql para excel e o relatório gera tudo certo, mas na hora de abrir o arquivo Excel (xls) ele aparece uma mensagem que o aquivo pode estar corrompido mais se clicar na opção sim ele abre o arquivo normalmente, como que faço para não exibir essa mensagem?

```
<?php
include_once('../db_functions.php');
$con = dbConnect();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Logs_de_Acesso</title>
    <head>
    <body>

        <?php

            $arquivo = 'Logs_de_Acesso.xls';
            $tabela = '<table border="1">';
            $tabela .= '<tr>';
            $tabela .= '<td colspan="6"><b><center>LOGS DE ACESSO - PORTAL CIRURGIAS RDV</center></b></td>';
            $tabela .= '</tr>';
            $tabela .= '<tr>';
            $tabela .= '<td><b>Id</b></td>';
            $tabela .= '<td><b>Host</b></td>';
            $tabela .= '<td><b>Ip</b></td>';
            $tabela .= '<td><b>Usuario_Nome</b></td>';
            $tabela .= '<td><b>Usuario_Papel</b></td>';
            $tabela .= '<td><b>Data_Evento</b></td>';
            $tabela .= '</tr>';

            function ConverteData($Data){
                if (strstr($Data, "/"))//verifica se tem a barra /
                {
                $d = explode ("/", $Data);//tira a barra
                $rstData = "$d[2]-$d[1]-$d[0]";//separa as datas $d[2] = ano $d[1] = mes etc...
                return $rstData;
                } elseif(strstr($Data, "-")){
                $d = explode ("-", $Data);
                $rstData = "$d[2]/$d[1]/$d[0]";
                return $rstData;
                }else{
                return "Data invalida";
                }
            }

            $data = ConverteData($_POST["data"]);
            $dataf = ConverteData($_POST["dataf"]);

            $sql = "SELECT * from activity_log_sql where data_evento >= '$data' and data_evento <= '$dataf' ORDER BY data_evento";

            $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            while($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

                $tabela .= '<tr>';
                $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['id'].'</td>';
                $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['host'].'</td>';
                $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['ip'].'</td>';
                $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['usuario_nome'].'</td>';
                $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['usuario_papel'].'</td>';
                $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['data_evento'].'</td>';
                $tabela .= '</tr>';
            }

            $tabela .= '</table>';

            // Força o Download do Arquivo Gerado
            header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
            header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
            header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
            header ("Pragma: no-cache");
            header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
            header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$arquivo}", date( 'dmY-His' ) );
            header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );

            echo $tabela;

            exit;
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Mensagem de erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente mudar o mime type para application/vnd.ms-excel, `header ("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excell");`  https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Basico_sobre_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

Comment: Se não resolver tente assim: header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8"); -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856355/php-excel-the-file-you-are-trying-to-open-xls-is-in-a-different-format-than-s ou com um dos outros formatos.

Comment: entao tentei desse jeitinho, mas não deu certo. Teria alguma outra sugestão. Já tentei varios jeitos e nada resolve :(

Comment: Não sei se pode ser isso, mas está faltando fechar o `head` no seu código. A tag de fechamento está apenas `<head>`, tem que ser `</head>`... esta pergunta no SO parece ter algumas outras alternativas para testar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368150/php-header-excel-and-utf-8/25822631

Comment: hummm vou testar desse jeito... obrigada